# Are first countable spaces are characterized by (C)?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space and let $g$ be a function from $N \times X$ into the topology of $X$ such that for all $x\in X$ and $n\in N$ , $x\in g(n,x)$.
We consider the following property of the function $g$.

> (C): If $x_n\in g(n,x)$ for all $n$, then $x$ is a cluster point of the sequence $\{x_n\}$.

Are first countable spaces are characterized by (C) with some separation axiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that $\{g(n,x):n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a base for the neighborhood system of $x.$ Otherwise, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $g(n,x)\not\subseteq U$ for all $n\in\mathbb N.$ Thus, for each $n\in\mathbb N,$ we can choose a point $x_n\in g(n,x)\setminus U.$ Then $x$ is not a cluster point of the sequence $\{x_n\},$ contrary to (C).

Comment: But $U=(0,1)$ is not a neighborhood of $x=0.$

Comment: What is your definition of cluster point of a sequence?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I find that I am wrong. Yes, thank you for your help!!!